# Install application using Inno Setup to a folder with current user name in its path (user profile)

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating an exe file with Inno Setup 5 compiler. I want to place the application by default at this location:

```
C:\users\username\AppData\local\appname
```

How can I get the user's Windows username?

with some kind of keyword like

```
C:\users\%AppData%\local\appname
```

or something that I could add in the script?

Comment: Further to the answers, to do a per user installation (which you are by installing into the profile) then you MUST use `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` to not try and elevate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I use the constant `{userappdata}` as described in the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=userappdata) to represent the %AppData% Windows constant which maps to c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming.
For example:

```
[Files]
Source: "c:\Build\output\test.dta"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\MyApplicaton\Data"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Comment: To get the local application data folder you could rather use `{localappdata}` constant (OP's path is not the user's application data path, but the path to the local application data). But all that has one (quite big) weakness. If you'll let the setup to elevate, these constants will return paths for the elevated user, which might differ from the one currently logged on to the system. Deanna pointed this in my (deleted) answer.

Comment: As the OP said they wanted a per user install (indirectly), then `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` is required anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to [InnoSetup docs](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm) the `{%username|DefaultValue}` can be used to get the username from environment variables. Keep in mind that the username and the name of the user folder can be different (as it is on my machine).